# Node - wait for map to finish before continuing

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, es6-promise

I have this file in my node app that supposed to go fetch me some data about every league champion from their official website using cheerio and its going all great but when I add all the data to my array to then return it as json data the write function runs before the map finishes so I just creating a json file with an empty array in it:

```
const request = require('request');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs');

const champions = fs.readFileSync('champions.json');
const championsObj = JSON.parse(champions);

let champsList = [];

championsObj.map(champ => {
  request(champ.href, (err, res, html) => {
    if (!err && res.statusCode == 200) {
      const $ = cheerio.load(html);

      const champName = $('.style__Title-sc-14gxj1e-3 span').text();

      let skins = [];

      const skinsList = $('.style__CarouselItemText-sc-1tlyqoa-16').each(
        (i, el) => {
          const skinName = $(el).text();
          skins.push = skinName;
        }
      );

      const champion = {
        champName,
        skins
      };

      console.log(champion);

      champsList.push = champion;
    }
  });
});

const jsonContent = JSON.stringify(champsList);

fs.writeFile('champions2.json', jsonContent, 'utf8', function(err) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
});
```

I'm not a node expert but I tried using Promise but it didn't work but I'm not sure maybe I used it wrong.

UPDATE #1: using axios

```
championsObj.map(async champ => {
  const html = await axios.get(champ.href);
  const $ = await cheerio.load(html);

  const champName = $('.style__Title-sc-14gxj1e-3 span').text();

  let skins = [];

  const skinsList = $('.style__CarouselItemText-sc-1tlyqoa-16').each(
    (i, el) => {
      const skinName = $(el).text();
      skins.push = skinName;
    }
  );

  const champion = {
    champName,
    skins
  };

  console.log(champion);

  champsList.push = champion;
});
```

Comment: the issue with this is that `request` is asynchronous - and the way you've written it, it's not guaranteed the `.map` will populate `champsList` in the right order

Comment: so you think axios or fetch might be a better option?

Comment: You say you tried promises, but haven't shown that code (fetch and axios use promises) - there's also "request-promise" npm module

Comment: one sec i'll update the question with the axios code

Comment: read about Promise.all on mdn. This is essential to what you are doing and to node programming in general. You don't need any fancy libraries to do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem here is that `Array#map` doesn't wait for asynchronous functions such as the `request` calls to finish before moving on. I recommend `p-map` with `got`. To ensure perfect execution order, I also recommend reading and writing the file asynchronously.

```js
const got = require('got');
const pMap = require('p-map');
const cheerio = require('cheerio');
const fs = require('fs').promises;

(async () => {
    const champions = JSON.parse(await fs.readFile('champions.json', 'utf8'));

    let champsList = await pMap(champions, async champ => {
        const {
            body
        } = await got(champ.href)

        const $ = cheerio.load(body);

        const champName = $('.style__Title-sc-14gxj1e-3 span').text();

        let skins = [];

        $('.style__CarouselItemText-sc-1tlyqoa-16').each(
            (_, el) => {
                const skinName = $(el).text();
                skins.push(skinName);
            }
        );

        const champion = {
            champName,
            skins
        };

        console.log(champion);

        return champion;
    })

    await fs.writeFile('champions2.json', JSON.stringify(champsList));
})();
```

Comment: this didn't work! I assume because 'html' is different from 'body' that got sends back? i tried to replace HTML with bod and it didn't work

Comment: @A.Atiyah What error are you getting? If you can provide the contents of champions.json, I can debug it myself.

Comment: the terminal just quits and writes an empty array
here's champions.json 
https://gofile.io/?c=KUa6WY
sorry didn't know how else to share it so I uploaded it there

Comment: I can just get the whole thing on github and link it if you're not comfortable downloading it

Comment: @A.Atiyah I need the **input** array for debugging, not the output one.

Comment: sorry accidentally uploaded the wrong one
https://gofile.io/?c=UgQepP

Comment: @A.Atiyah Turns it, it was just incorrect variable names. I've updated the code in my answer.

Comment: oh my god while i was experimenting with request before your answer it turned out I may've deleted the file data and that's why I also uploaded it empty the first time I'm sorry haha,

Comment: It did but it output an empty skins array.  how do I fix this one?

Comment: @A.Atiyah Did you re-copy over the new code and `npm install`ed?

Comment: oh yes I did and it worked fine now, I'm sorry for the confusion I'm newer to node :)

Answer (score 5):

you can use `await Promise.all(<array>.map(async () => {...})`. it does not require any additional dependencies. however you have no guarantees about the order of asynchronous iterations (starting all the iterations in the right order, but no guarantees about iterations' endings).